# Dynamically created temporary table does not persist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a temporary table in a dynamic query and use it afterwards. It will be created from a permanent table:

```
create table t (a integer);
insert into t values (1);
```

And the temp table creation is like this:

```
declare @command varchar(max) = '
    select *
    into #t
    from t
    ;
    select * from #t;
';
execute (@command);
```

When the @command is executed the `select from` the temporary table works.

Now if I select from the temporary table an error message is shown:

```
select * from #t;

Invalid object name '#t'
```

If the temporary table is created outside of the dynamic query it works:

```
select top 0 *
into #t
from t

declare @command varchar(max) = '
    insert into #t
    select *
    from t
';
execute (@command);

select * from #t;
```

Is it possible to persist a dynamically created temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create global temporary tables.  For example, ##MyTemp. 
But, global temporary tables are visible to all SQL Server connections.

Comment: I tested and it works. So I guess the problem is that the dynamic query is executed in a different session or something like that? I will not use a global temporary btw.

Comment: I use them with all stringcoded executes in some procedures, the tablenames are here generated from NEW_ID(). I don't like that, but have some special cases of long running complex procedures.

Answer (score 2):

You are close in your assumption that `EXECUTE` is carried out in a different session.

According to the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL
>   batch

So your temporary table only exists inside the scope of the SQL executed by the `EXECUTE` command.

Comment: Is that because a transaction executes in a different session and not because of the transaction itself? A global temporary survives the transaction.

Comment: AFAIK everything should execute in the same session, WHY global temps survive the transaction I don't know, but they don't survive if the execute SQL is transaction wrapped: (you'll need to run this locally) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6819/2